# Need 2 way binding between 2 components flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

Can anyone tell me how to do 2-way Binding between 2 components?

I have a TabGroup, in which I created 2 tabs.. Each tab has each component...

**First tab:** Some form is there and submit button
**Second Tab:** Datagrid

So, when I enter some details and click Submit button, 1 row should be added in Datagrid.. This functionality is working, BUT when i double click the row in Datagrid, the row details from Datagrid should be filled up in Form which iam not getting this..

**PLease check below code , run it, and provide me solution:**

**Main.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"  
               xmlns:components="components.*"
               creationComplete="init()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import components.EmployeeSingleton;

            [Bindable]
            public var empSingleton: EmployeeSingleton;

            public function init(): void
            {
                empSingleton = EmployeeSingleton.getInstance();
            }


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>


    <s:VGroup>

        <s:TabBar dataProvider="{contact}" />

        <mx:ViewStack id="contact"
                      resizeToContent="true">

            <components:ContactInfo id="contactInfo"
                                    label="Employee Info" 
                                    empSingleton="{empSingleton}"/>

            <components:ContactList label="Employee List"
                                    empSingleton="{empSingleton}"/>


        </mx:ViewStack>

    </s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

**EmployeeSingleton.as**

```
package components
{
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    [Bindable]
    public final class EmployeeSingleton
    {
        private static var instance: EmployeeSingleton;
        public var empData: ArrayCollection;

        public function EmployeeSingleton()
        {
        }

        public static function getInstance(): EmployeeSingleton 
        {
            if(instance == null)
                instance = new EmployeeSingleton();

            return instance;
        }


    }
}
```

**EmployeeVO.as**

```
package vo
{
    [Bindable]
    public class EmployeeVO
    {
        public function EmployeeVO()
        {
        }

        public var empName: String;
        public var address: String;
        public var state: String;
        public var city: String;
        public var zip: String;


    }
}
```

**ContactInfo.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:NavigatorContent xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            import vo.EmployeeVO;

            public var empSingleton: EmployeeSingleton;

            private var empVO : EmployeeVO;
            private var empCollection : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();


            protected function submit_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                empVO = new EmployeeVO();

                empVO.empName = empName.text;
                empVO.address = address.text;
                empVO.city = city.text;
                empVO.state = state.text;
                empVO.zip = zip.text;

                empCollection.addItem(empVO);

                empSingleton.empData = empCollection;

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Form>

        <s:FormItem label="Name">
            <s:TextInput id="empName" />
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:FormItem label="Address">
            <s:TextInput id="address" />
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:FormItem label="City">
            <s:TextInput id="city" />
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:FormItem label="State">
            <s:TextInput id="state" />
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:FormItem label="Zip">
            <s:TextInput id="zip" />
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:FormItem>
            <s:Button id="submit"
                      label="Submit"
                      click="submit_clickHandler(event)"/>
        </s:FormItem>

    </s:Form>

</s:NavigatorContent>
```

**ContactList.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:NavigatorContent xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300"
         >

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            public var empSingleton: EmployeeSingleton;

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:DataGrid id="empData"
                dataProvider="{empSingleton.empData}"/>

</s:NavigatorContent>
```

**Awaiting for solution, please run above code and provide me solution for 2-way binding**

Comment: Can anyone please reply for my query?

Comment: I don't see anything in your form that is trying to bind to anything. And, since you're already using Dependency Injection (good), it seems silly that at the root of it all is a Singleton ([bad](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/11/21/clean-code-talks-global-state-and-singletons/)). Why not just create the one instance at the top level and just use that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind for 'update for on double click on an item in list'. Bindings are very tightly coupled. What you should do instead is listen for double-click events on list and update form with a item information that was double-clicked on.